# Apply functions on each group in Data Frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Stack Overflow and new to programming. I am learning Scala.
I have the following data frame:

| id | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | 2021-01-09 | 2021-01-15 |
| James | 2021-01-14 | 2198-01-01 |
| James | 2021-01-22 | null |
| Sara | 2021-01-16 | 2198-01-01 |
| Sara | 2021-02-23 | null |

I need to find the rows where the `to` value is set to `2198-01-01` and update them with the `from` value where the `to` column is `null` for each `id` group. For example, for James, the `to` value in row 2 will be updated with the `from` value from row 3.

Desired output:

| id | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | 2021-01-09 | 2021-01-15 |
| James | 2021-01-14 | 2021-01-22 |
| James | 2021-01-22 | null |
| Sara | 2021-01-16 | 2021-02-23 |
| Sara | 2021-02-23 | null |

I wrote a  function that extracts the value, but I'm struggling with applying this function for each `id` group.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType

val df = Seq(
("James", "2021-01-09", "2021-01-15"),
("James", "2021-01-14", "2198-01-01"),
("James", "2021-01-22", null),
("Sara", "2021-01-16", "2198-01-01"),
("Sara", "2021-02-23", null)
).toDF("id",  "from", "to")

def myFunc1(df: DataFrame) = {
  val strs = df.select("from").where($"to".isNull).as[String].collect
  strs(0)
}

def extractValue(df: DataFrame)= {
  df.withColumn(
        "id",
        when(
         $"to" === "2198-01-01",
          myFunc1(df))
      )}
```

I thought I'd be able to do something like this `df.groupBy("id").transform(extractValue(df))`, but this doesn't work.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: There will always be at least one row with a `null` value and one row with `2198-01-01` value per group. If there multiple null values I need to take the latest from value and update with it

Comment: does it always have a null value if it has `to` as `2198-01-01`? what if there are multiple null values?

Comment: Yes, there will always be at least one row with a null value and one row with 2198-01-01 value.
If there multiple null values I need to take the latest from value and update with it.

Comment: What is the ordering, how do you know the latest?

Comment: It's a date, so the newest date. For example: if there is ("Sara", "2021-02-23", null) and ("Sara", "2021-02-25", null)  2021-02-25 is the newer date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `when` to mask the irrelevant values, and get the `max` `From` date where `To` is null:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "To",
    when(
        $"to" === lit("2198-01-01"),
        max(when($"To".isNull, $"From")).over(Window.partitionBy("id"))
    ).otherwise($"to")
)

df2.show
+-----+----------+----------+
|   id|      From|        To|
+-----+----------+----------+
|James|2021-01-09|2021-01-15|
|James|2021-01-14|2021-01-22|
|James|2021-01-22|      null|
| Sara|2021-01-16|2021-02-23|
| Sara|2021-02-23|      null|
+-----+----------+----------+
```